# Intent data is null in OnActivityResult(Bluetooth)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, bluetooth

Need help. I want to pass data to the `CallBack` method, but I get a null value.

```
Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
enableBt.PutExtra("Resource", "bluetooth");
StartActivityForResult(enableBt, 1);
```

and

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        var resource = data.GetStringExtra("Resource");
```

But `data = null`. What is the problem?

Comment: The docs state that the only information you can get back from that is an appropriate `resultCode`. You can't expect the `Activity` that handles that action to return any data `Intent`, let alone one that has been populated with any arbitrary extras that you've set on the launch `Intent`. That goes for pretty much any `Intent` that launches an external component, unless otherwise specified in the docs (though I'm not aware of any that will preserve your extras).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we usually need to use `requestCode` and `resultCode` to filter the intent.
Besides, we also need to use method `SetResult` to return the result. 
You can refer to the following code:

The First Page

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
StartActivityForResult(intent, 0x001);
```

method: OnActivityResult

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0x001)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                string result = data.GetStringExtra("test");

                Toast.MakeText(this,"reslut is: " + result,ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

        }
    }
```

The SecondPage

```
var intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra("test", "test..123");
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
Finish();
```